# USB flash drive connects randomly / only sometimes

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure

So this problem keeps reoccurring even on new flash drives, and I can't stand it. I have some usb flash drives, and whenever I try to connect them to my laptop (triple boot, so no OS specific), I have to try again and again, shake them, till the computer logs a pci change and then eventually mounts them.
A little background info, I have a functioning usb mouse, which always connects instantly, and I've tried connecting other usb which work, so I'm thinking it's not because of the laptop ports, but the flash drives themselves. The question is though, what may be causing this unwanted behaviour and is there a way to fix it. (I mostly use those usb drives for live usbs, and it's pretty unpleasant when BIOS doesn't detect them).
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port?

Comment: I've tried it on the 3 usb ports that my laptop has, and also on another laptop. The success rate is random, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't connect at all...

Comment: Well, you kind of answered yourself there - your flash drives may be faulty. It can be a wear of the actual USB connection on the drives themselves, which prevents the PC to see that they are plugged in. You say you are using the same flash drives mostly, so this can explain it the best. Try plugin these flash drives to another PC, to check that theory.